# Forest plotが描けない

Tags: r

下記で Forest plot を描こうとするのですが

```
forestplot.default(row_names, test_data$coef, test_data$low,
```

```
エラー: You have provided 22 rows in your mean arguement while the labels have 2 rows
```

とエラーメッセージが出て描くことができません。何が問題なのでしょうか？

プログラムの全体は、下記の通りです。

```
 library("forestplot")
 data <- read.csv("Data3.csv")
 forestplot(row_names,
 + data$coef,
 + data$low,
 + data$high,
 + zero = 1,
 + cex = 2,
 + lineheight = "auto",
 + xlab = "Lab axis txt")
```

データはcsvファイル(UTF-8)"Data3.csv"で下記の通りです。

```
     coef    low  high
1  0.9544 0.8037 1.133
2  1.2260 0.9464 1.588
3  0.8508 0.6347 1.141
4  0.8956 0.6998 1.146
5  1.1530 0.9099 1.460
6  1.2050 0.9301 1.562
7  1.0110 0.7493 1.365
8  1.0330 0.8025 1.330
9  1.0510 0.8119 1.362
10 1.3000 1.0140 1.668
11 0.8805 0.6592 1.176
12 1.1440 0.8922 1.467
13 1.2140 0.9473 1.557
14 1.1050 0.8903 1.372
15 1.0560 0.8053 1.384
16 1.4700 1.1610 1.862
17 0.8101 0.5748 1.142
18 0.8746 0.6843 1.118
19 1.1590 0.8968 1.497
20 1.1070 0.8719 1.406
21 1.1050 0.6864 1.778
22 0.9251 0.7232 1.183
```

Comment: 「mean argumentとして与えたデータ数と、与えたlabelの数が合っていない」（データは22個あるのに、labelは2つしかない）というのがエラーメッセージの内容なのですから、どのようなデータを用意して、プログラムに入れたのかを確認してください。
プログラムの断片から、そこに与えたデータが何であるかを推測する事は不可能です。
必要であれば、プログラムの全体と、そこで使ったデータの仕様を質問に追加して下さい。そうすれば、回答できる人が居るかもしれませんから。

Comment: 添付されたコードを実行すると、row_namesが定義されていないエラーが発生しましたが、添付コード以外で定義されたものでしょうか?

Comment: 質問者さんのアカウントがふたつに分かれてしまっているかもしれません。質問者さんのアカウントであればご自身の質問文を自由に編集できます。[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますので、お試しください。